# Compilation error with std::cout outputting int

Tags: c++, string

In my program, I try to have the user input a `std::string`, then store the length of that string in a variable and print that variable. However, I get compilation errors. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    int len = str.length();
    std::cout >> len;

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors I receive:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
D:\C(Beginners)\palindrome.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
D:\C(Beginners)\palindrome.cpp|11|error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'int')|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\istream|808|note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\istream|808|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
D:\C(Beginners)\palindrome.cpp|11|note:   'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\istream|803|note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\istream|803|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
D:\C(Beginners)\palindrome.cpp|11|note:   'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\istream|761|note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\istream|761|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
D:\C(Beginners)\palindrome.cpp|11|note:   'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\istream|756|note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\istream|756|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
D:\C(Beginners)\palindrome.cpp|11|note:   'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc|923|note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc|923|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
D:\C(Beginners)\palindrome.cpp|11|note:   'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc|955|note: candidate: template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc|955|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
D:\C(Beginners)\palindrome.cpp|11|note:   'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc|1441|note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc|1441|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
D:\C(Beginners)\palindrome.cpp|11|note:   'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: post the errors here. All the relevant information required to answer should be contained in the post, not behind a 3rd party link.

Comment: btw it's just 1 error and it's wrongly using `>>` on `cout`. Change to `std::cout << len;`. Vote to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want
`std::cout << len`

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is `std::cout << len`, but you write `std::cout >> len`.

In other words, you are using the wrong operator.  The `>>` operator is used for `std::cin`, not `std::cout`.

A good way to remember this is to see which way the arrows are pointing. For `std::cin`, the arrows point toward the variable because the computer is writing the input *to* a variable. For `std::cout`, the arrows pointing left represent writing output to `cout`.

This explains the first error that you receive:

`error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'int')|`

The error says that the operand type `std::ostream` (which `std::cout` is part of) has no operator `>>`.